# SSRS Timeline Chart for each day / minute

Tags: sql-server, ssrs, reporting

I'm asked to make a Timeline Bar Chart with SSRS 2012.
There should be 1 chart per day/employee, and this chart should have a x-axis of 1440 minutes (or 24 hours).
The bar should have 2 different colors, which represent the 2 different status of the employee (working / not working).

The table from which I get the data has following columns:

```
    Starttime_working (datetime), Endtime_Working (datetime), Duration_worktime (int), Duration_till_next_worktime(int)
```

There could be many of this entries per day for one employee. The duration columns are seconds.

I think I have to transform this data to get a result like:

```
    2013-03-02 16:52:00 - working
    2013-03-02 16:53:00 - working
    2013-03-02 16:54:00 - working
    2013-03-02 16:55:00 - working
    2013-03-02 16:56:00 - not working
    2013-03-02 16:57:00 - not working
```

Is this the right data format for generating a Timeline Chart?
Are there other ways to get what I want?
Any general tips for creating a timeline-chart with ssrs?

Comment: Which part of this are you having problems with?

Comment: The questions is, what is the right data-format for a bar chart to display a time period over 24 hours on the x-axis, which has 2 different status (working/not). Can I work with my existing table structure in SSRS or do I have do convert it to another format, like this I mentioned (which would give me a huge amount of data 1440*365 rows for one employee per year)

Comment: I believe the answer on this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870686/how-do-i-create-a-timeline-chart-which-shows-multiple-events-eg-metallica-band, can help you.

Comment: Try the "Range Bar" type of graph (that's what it's called in 2008 anyway). That looks the closest to me. I'm not sure if you can plug in the endpoints of the ranges, or if you need to expand out to the minute. Play with it, and see what happens.